# Simple jQuery form Validation: Checking for empty .val() failing in ie9 due to placeholder polyfill

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

***New Issue / Answer***

I am using an HTML5 placeholder polyfill which is causing ie9 to set the input's placeholder text as the value. So while in HTML5 browsers the val attribute is empty, in the below code ie9 is seeing it as filled in.

---

I'm using jQuery to make sure all fields are filled in. This works fine in ie10, webkit, and mozilla but fails in ie9.

What am I doing wrong here, and why won't this code work in ie9?

Thank you!

```
$('#quoteform .button.next').on('click',function(){
    var $me = $(this),
        $myParent = $me.parent(),
        $nextStep = $myParent.nextAll('fieldset:not(.disabled)').first(),
        validate;

    // If we're on step2, make sure all fields are filled in            
    if($me.is('#quote-step2 .button') || $me.is('#quote-step1 .button')) {
        $me.parents('fieldset').find('input:visible').each(function(){
            var $me = $(this),
                myVal = this.value;

            if(myVal === '') {
                $me.parent().addClass('warning');
                validate = false;
                return;             
            } else {
                if(typeof validate === 'undefined')
                    validate = true;
            }
        });
    }

    if(validate === false) {
        alert('Please fill out all fields before continuing.');
        return false;
    }

    switchView($nextStep, $myParent);
});
```

Comment: Did you look at your browser's console to see if any errors? What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: If you look at what happens in mozilla, webkit, and ie10, then look at ie9, you can see exactly what doesn't work. Thanks! There are no errors in console. I think it may be related to :visible though

Comment: I know I **can** do that, but we shouldn't have to. You shouldn't come here expecting us to do all the work and figure it out. An explanation here goes a long way, as well as a localized demo (like on jsFiddle.net). Also, how do you know we all have access to every browser version and can test it ourselves? Again, a better explanation would help. As I have now taken the time, I do see the difference. I'll look more closely at it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and my workaround was to also test the value against the placeholder string in addition to testing for an empty value.  Since the polyfill replaces the input's value with the placeholder string the empty value is the value of the placeholder in IE9.

```
    $me.parents('fieldset').find('input:visible').each(function(){
        var $me = $(this),
            myVal = this.value,
            myPlaceholder = $me.attr('placeholder');

        if(myVal === '' || myVal === myPlaceholder) {
            $me.parent().addClass('warning');
            validate = false;
            return;             
        } else {
            if(typeof validate === 'undefined')
                validate = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for that, Ken! Worked like a charm.